# Middle Align Multiple Div Elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to middle align 2 divs. I have tried many answers on SO but no success.

Can anyone please help?

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
.upload-text-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.upload-text-wrapper:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image-frame" src="http://www.telecomwiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/free-stock-photo-brick-wall-imageslive-decorating-a-white-brick-wall-decoration-picture-white-brick-wall-120x120." />
  <div class="upload-text-wrapper">
    <div class="upload-button-icon">X</div>
    <div class="upload-button-title">control 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to align `upload-button-icon` and `upload-button-title` in middle both vertically and horizontally on hover without changing the existing html structure.

Comment: middle align = vertical centering? (or just horizontal)?

Comment: both vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
.upload-button-icon, .upload-button-title {
    text-align:center;
     transform: translateY(35px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xs0gc0r2/4/ Note: you can change translateY value to fit your needs... Note2: not sure about css/ how you will style these divs, some tweaks will be needed, probably. This works with provided html/css...

Comment: If you don't mind can you please add the tweaks? Thanks

Comment: Np, horizontal centering will work if divs have 100% width of their parent, about vertical centering -> since you have fixed height of parent: 120px, there shouldn't be problems...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's good to use this variant that does not use CSS3:
You can support older browsers and won't have to adjust the translateY-value when the image size changes.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: table;
}
.image-frame {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.upload-text-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
}
.image-container:hover .upload-text-wrapper{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image-frame" src="http://www.telecomwiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/free-stock-photo-brick-wall-imageslive-decorating-a-white-brick-wall-decoration-picture-white-brick-wall-120x120." />
  <div class="upload-text-wrapper">
    <div class="upload-button-icon">X</div>
    <div class="upload-button-title">control 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```